# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: UPDATE statement on table expected to update X row(s); Y were matched

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Using sqlalchemy 2.0.21 with postgresql 14, I have the following model:

```py
class MyModel(TimestampedMixin):
    id = Column(String(12), primary_key=True)
    rating = Column(Float, index=True)
    ... more fields ...
```

Inspired by the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-bulk-update-by-primary-key), I want to update all `rating` values (currently Null) for each **matching** `id` from a list of dicts. If `id` is not already in the database it should ignore that dict and continue, since it's an update op...

```py
        # ...
        sess.flush()
        sess.execute(
            update(MyModel),
            [
                {
                    'id': row[0],   # str, may or may not exist
                    'rating': row[1]   # float, Null so far
                }
                for row in values  # values is a list of lists
            ]
        )
        sess.commit()
```

But I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/scripts/populate_db.py", line 128, in <module>
    sess.execute(
  File "/home/user/.venv/project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2262, in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
  File "/home/user/.venv/project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2144, in _execute_internal
    result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(
  File "/home/user/.venv/project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/bulk_persistence.py", line 1596, in orm_execute_statement
    result = _bulk_update(
  File "/home/user/.venv/project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/bulk_persistence.py", line 332, in _bulk_update
    persistence._emit_update_statements(
  File "/home/user/.venv/project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 943, in _emit_update_statements
    raise orm_exc.StaleDataError(
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: UPDATE statement on table 'mymodel' expected to update 80000 row(s); 24017 were matched.
python-BaseException
```

which I don't get the reasoning why it shouldn't be the expected behavior. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You passed in this list to `sess.execute()`:

```
            [
                {
                    'id': row[0],   # str, may or may not exist
                    'rating': row[1]   # float, Null so far
                }
                for row in values  # values is a list of lists
            ]
```

Since you are not first checking if `row[0]` exists, you're basically just creating a long list of rows to update (i.e., `[ {'id': 1, 'rating': 0.0}, {'id': 2, 'rating': 1.1} ... ]`).  Postgres will allow you to do the updates without complaining, but SQLAlchemy will not.  It attempts to perform an `UPDATE` for each item in that list, and keeps track of which ones successfully matched a row in the database.  If it doesn't then it complains.

To get around this limitation, you'll need to query the database first:

```
    sess.flush()
    for row in values:
        r = db_session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.id == row[0])
        r_exists = r.first()
        if r_exists:
            sess.execute(update(MyModel,[{'id': row[0], 'rating': row[1]}]))
        ...
    sess.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks. Sure, but I was looking for a bulk update to avoid separate lookup (filter) queries for performance optimization. If I get an instance back, then I suppose I could also do `r_exists.rating = row[1]`